# Serving a stored file with a controller and best place to store file

Tags: magento, csv, feed

I'm creating a feed in CSV file format for products in magento.

We already have some CSV files generated on the fly and returned by magento controller.

But I would like to pre-generate the file and save it in some place and directly return the file upon request.

Where is the best place to save this file?

And how can I return it from controller?

BTW, the file is rarely accessed, so I don't want to store it in memcache, just as a generic *file.csv*

Comment: Does the controller still need to serve up the file, or when you say "pre-generate", do you mean that it would be already generated ahead of time (e.g. via a cron job)?  As for saving, placing it somewhere within the `var` directory would make the most sense.

Comment: yes, the file is generated before already. I need to serve it with controller or without.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a directory under {Magento Base Install Path}/var/ would be a logical place to cache the file.

To return the file from the controller you can use:

```
$fileName = 'file.csv'
$filePath = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . '/csvfilecache/' . $fileName;
$content = array('type' => 'filename', 'value' => $filePath);
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content, 'text/csv');
```

See `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_prepareDownloadResponse`